# How to prevent authtenticated page flasshing the login page VUEJS 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router4

I am using vue3 can I ask for some help why is it redirecting to an authenticated page like home, when I refresh the login page will flash. every time I refresh it keeps flashing, how can I prevent this flashing login when I refresh the page or anywhere as long as I'm authenticated.

Thank you in advance.

// main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { store } from '@/vuex/store.js';

import router from './router';

const app = createApp(App)


app.use(store);
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

//router

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '@/views/HomeView.vue'

import Login from '@/components/Login.vue'

// @ts-ignore
import {store} from "@/vuex/store";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,

        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            component: HomeView
        }

    ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

 next()
})

export default router
```

// login.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
   <h1>Login </h1>
      <form action="#" method="post">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" id="username" v-model="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="password" id="password" v-model="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="icheck-primary">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember">
                <label for="remember">
                  Remember Me
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" @click.prevent="login">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
          </div>
        </form>
   </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
import {useStore} from 'vuex'
import {useRouter} from 'vue-router';


const username = ref('');
const password = ref('');

const store = useStore();
const router = useRouter();


const login = async () => {

  await store.dispatch('fetchToken', {username: username.value, password: password.value});
  await store.dispatch('fetchUserLogin');
  await router.push({name: 'home'});
}


</script>
```

// App.vue

```
<template>

  <router-view v-if="store.state.isLogin"/>
  <login v-else></login>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Login from '@/components/Login.vue'

import {useStore} from 'vuex';
import {RouterView} from "vue-router";
import {onBeforeMount, onMounted, ref} from "vue";

const store = useStore();


onMounted(async ()=>{
  await store.dispatch('fetchUserLogin')
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<router-view v-if="store.state.isLogin"/>
<login v-else></login>
```

while `store.state.isLogin` is false, the page will show the Login component.  `store.state.isLogin` is always initially false until this asychronous operation completes:

```js
await store.dispatch('fetchUserLogin')
```

That's why you always see a flash of the login component.  `store.state.isLogin` is **false** until the dispatch is complete, which takes some small amount of time.

There are multiple ways you could handle this, one would be to have a `isLoading` property that is initially true and is then set to false once the `fetchUserLogin` is done.  You can use `isLoading` to choose to not render anything (or render some loading modal) while the fetching is ongoing:

```html
<div v-if="isLoading"></div>
<div v-else>
  <router-view v-if="store.state.isLogin"/>
  <login v-else></login>
</div>
```

```js
const store = useStore();
const isLoading = true;

onMounted(async () => {
  await store.dispatch('fetchUserLogin');
  isLoading = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is it okay to put the isLoading to my vuex store, then I will dispatch and commit it to update the value ?